# How to create an alert dialog with "more" or "details" expendable section?

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, alert

I am interested in displaying an alert to a user with OK button to close the alert, and a more/details button which upon clicking on it displays certain details (text, table, data, etc). Can it be done using PHP/HTML alone?

Comment: Displaying simple alerts is possible through pure HTML/CSS but for the "more" option you would need javascript unless you want to generate your alert box at the server and then bring it to the client side....

Comment: You can do an expand/contract with PHP/HTML, yes - this requires a form submission and a full page redraw. The customary way of dealing with this is to use JavaScript, but it is not absolutely required.

Comment: With "PHP/HTML alone" you mean without JavaScript? With JS yes, of course it can be. Without will required a roundtrip to server. CSS only solution **may** be possible (for hover) but...what for?

Comment: You can not do this with the standard alert dialog. You will have to implement this yourself.

Comment: Thank you all. Any suggestions on how? I came across this bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html but it does not have any popup alerts.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ might point you in the right direction. You should really consider using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you're describing is possible, but would not be the accepted or fastest way of doing it. Using PHP requires a trip back to the server which reloads the page - not something you want to be doing if you want easy usability.

The recommended solution is to use Javascript, or jQuery. I would recommend against using jQuery UI unless you're going to use more than one part of it - it's a great library but it has much more functionality than you need and unless you host the file yourself, the download you get from major CDNs is large and will take a while to load.

However, there is a solution I know of and have use called Alertify. It is a JS plugin that deals specifically with alert, confirm and prompt dialog boxes, and can be fully customised. Here's the site if you want to have a look: https://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/. It comes with demos and example code so you can adapt that to your purposes.

Comment: OK, Here is the actual issue I am facing; I have a form on the page and I check `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` (PHP). I take it is being processed before the HTML loads and that is why I get the "undefined" error - but if I put the alert in the `onLoad()` function (JS) it loads just fine. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you expand a bit? What are you trying to achieve and what are you going to do with the result of the request type check? And what does the error say is undefined?